# Why does my button become a rectangle when i use pseudo type :before

Tags: html, css

Please, why is my button rectangular instead of round. When I set the top, left, right, bottom properties.

I expected a moved round button absolute from the website.

```
button{
    height:60px;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    margin:0 35px;
    border-radius:50px;
    outline:none;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    background:#111;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

css

```
button:last-child:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:inherit;
    top:-5px;
    right:-5px;
    bottom:-5px;
    left:-5px;


}
```

Comment: please add [example]

Comment: button:last-child:hover{
    background:linear-gradient(90deg,#03a9f4, #f441a5,#ffeb3b, #03a9fa);
    background-size:400%;
}

button:last-child:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:inherit;
    top:-5px;
    right:-5px;
    bottom:-5px;
    left:-5px;


}

Comment: edit the question and add code on that

Comment: ok i will do so

Answer (score 1):

Just add `overflow: hidden` to the button, preventing the ::before pseudo from showing up outside the border-radius of its parent.

Btw I wouldn't use position properties (top, right, bottom, left) to set size to a pseudo element, I'd rather stick to width and height properties and left the former to actually position it inside the element, but that's just the way I'm used to approaching it.